# Reactjs Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

In my backend, which is nodejs for information only, the data is returned fine

But I had to populate the data returned in the response

To show the name of the user, not his ID

The response returns in the following form

[image]

When I try to access the username, which is in this case (realName ) in my react application, a problem occurs as in the title of this question

I am attaching all the information and if anyone needs more information, do not hesitate to request it

**this hook**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getOneTicket } from "../../store/actions";

const TicketsDetailsHook = (id) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //to get state from redux
  const { ticketsDetiles, isTicketCreated, error } = useSelector((state) => ({
    ticketsDetiles: state.Tickets.ticketsDetiles,
    isTicketCreated: state.Tickets.isTicketCreated,
    error: state.Tickets.error,
  }));



  let item = [];
  if(isTicketCreated===true){
    if (ticketsDetiles){
        item = ticketsDetiles;
        console.log(ticketsDetiles);
      } 
  }

  
  //else{item = [];} 

  //when first load
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getOneTicket(id))
}, [])


  return [item];
};

export default TicketsDetailsHook;
```

**this components**

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { Col, Row } from "reactstrap";
import TicketsDetailsHook from "../../../Hooks/TicketsHooks/TicketsDetailsHook";
const Section = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [item] = TicketsDetailsHook(id);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Col lg={12}>
        <div className="bg-soft-warning">
          <Row>
            <div className="col-md">
              <h4 className="fw-semibold" id="ticket-title">
                erere
              </h4>
              <div className="hstack gap-3 flex-wrap">
                <div className="text-muted">
                  <i className="ri-building-line align-bottom me-1"></i>{" "}
                  <span id="ticket-client">{item.addedBy.realName}</span> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Row>
        </div>
      </Col>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Section;
```

This line is not accepted and herein lies the problem

**{item.addedBy.realName}**

note :

If I cancel the populate  process, everything works fine, of course, except that I will get the ID for the laser, and not its name

**this console.log(item)**
[image]

**this conslo.log component file**
[image]

The error only appears when I try to log in

**item.addedBy.realName**

This is the error log in the console

**Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_id, realName, id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**

As you can see, the rest of the data is fetched correctly, except for

**{item.data?.addedBy.realName}**
[image]
return empty
[image]

Comment: It's `item.data.addedBy.realName` that you want to access.

Comment: Or rather, it's `item.data` that you want to be throwing into Redux, not `item`. If you're already doing that, try throwing another log in to see what `item` is when you pull it with the hook.

Comment: As you can see, I sent the item as an array from the hook
I don't know where you got item.data from

Comment: @ivanatias Thanks for your reply. I updated the question and attached the log

Comment: @ZacAnger Thanks for your reply. I updated the question and attached the log

Comment: can you log item value in the component file?

Comment: @ProsenjitChongder There is no difference is the same value returned from the hook
Question updated

Comment: I'm not seeing any obvious problems based on your updates. Can you try `{console.log(item.addedBy.realName) || item.addedBy.realName}` in that span and see what it logs out?

Comment: @ZacAnger Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'realName')

Comment: How about `{item && item.addedBy.realName}` to be sure `item` has been fetched and put into state before being used?

Comment: @ZacAnger I've tried for you
When I am on the page that actually contains the component, the name is changed, but as soon as I refresh the page or go back and back, the error appears again and the page does not load
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'realName')

Comment: How come react recognize the hook without using the `use` prefix in the name `TicketsDetailsHook`?

Answer (score 1):

**In the `Section` component, It should be: `item.data?.addedBy.realName`.**

The `?` is for the case the item is  an empty array, which will happen when the `isTicketCreated` is **false**.

And yes, you did send `item` as an array from the hook, but when you use the hook  in the `Section` you extract it from that array in this line:  `const [item] = TicketsDetailsHook(id);`

So it will still be an object, and you just need to access the `data` field in it.

**Note:**
If you where importing the item from the hook like this:

```
const item = TicketsDetailsHook(id);
```

Then, it will be an array because you didn't distructure it. So in this case you would access the data like this: `item[0].data?.addedBy.realName`

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I've tried it
The error appears like this
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: Edited the answer, it should be `item.data?.addedBy.realName`

Comment: Do you mean I need to modify that in the hook?
Please clarify, thank you

Comment: Not in the hook, you just need to change the line of where you return the `span` with the name in the `Section` component. Change it to: `<span id="ticket-client">{item.data?.addedBy.realName}</span>`

Comment: The value is fetched as empty. True, the error disappears, but no value is received

Comment: No value is recived because the is **no data**. In your hook you checked if the `isTicketCreated` is true or false. When it's true - `item` will contain the card data, and when it's false - `item` will be an **empty array**, So in this case when you try to print the name it won't show anything because there is no data of the card to show.

Comment: Sir, the strange thing is that if you ask for something other than addedBy.realName
It is properly brought and put in place

Answer (score 0):

you should only `return item` from the hook

and try to `console.log(item)` in your component.

Comment: It is actually being pulled back from the hook

Comment: can you check the console.log(typeof item.addedBy.realName, item.addedBy.realName ), 
let me know the console values...

Comment: the value string

Comment: it is working fine man, I forked it on codesendbox you can see this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-platform-989y5c?file=/src/App.js